# react-django csrf token error using react-cookie package

Tags: django, reactjs

```
import cookie from 'react-cookies';
const csrfToken = cookie.load('csrftoken')

onSubmitSignUp = () => {
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers:{
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
}
```

Here i am sending some data to django.to send csrf token i am using 'react-cookie' as per the documentation. but in python side it is showing
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /register/
[11/Nov/2018 11:56:33] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2868